Struggling with an eth_call query
I am trying to eth_call the ownerOf method for an nft contract. I am sending the token id but I get the same response address no matter how I change the padded token id. It always seems to give me the response of the address containing token id 0.
My params are like so. For example I am querying BAYC NFT contract. Is the padded token id incorrect?
My curl statement is below.
curl --location 'https://ethereum-rpc.publicnode.com/' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"jsonrpc": "2.0","method": "eth_call","params": [{"to": "0xBC4CA0EdA7647A8aB7C2061c2E118A18a936f13D","data": "0x6352211e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"},"latest"],"id": 1}

I am not sure why my response never changes as I change the second value.

Please check out the solution below! :)

Actually you have a redundant empty bytes gap which breaks the encoded data:
console.log("0x6352211e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002".length)
// ==> 74
console.log("0x6352211e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001".length)
// ==> 98

My corrected data below is 74-characters long, and your data is 24 bytes larger for some reason.
That's where the problem comes from.
This corrected cURL request actually works correctly in my Git Bash, according to the tests:
$ curl --location 'https://ethereum-rpc.publicnode.com/' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"jsonrpc": "2.0","method": "eth_call","params": [{"to": "0xBC4CA0EdA7647A8aB7C2061c2E118A18a936f13D","data": "0x6352211e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002"},"latest"],"id": 1}'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   309  100   103  100   206    248    497 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   751{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x000000000000000000000000c5c7b46843014b1591e9af24de797156cde67f08"}

Proof:


And:
$ curl --location 'https://ethereum-rpc.publicnode.com/' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"jsonrpc": "2.0","method": "eth_call","params": [{"to": "0xBC4CA0EdA7647A8aB7C2061c2E118A18a936f13D","data": "0x6352211e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"},"latest"],"id": 1}'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   309  100   103  100   206    203    406 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   613{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x00000000000000000000000046efbaedc92067e6d60e84ed6395099723252496"}


Although the response contains an unpadded address because it returns a bytes32 as per the default, the address is still correct.

Hopefully, that addresses your concerns and fixes the problem! :)

Success!! Yes, that was it!!
